# Apache Spark MLlib ALS. Duplicate user-item pairs

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, collaborative-filtering

I am using Spark MLlib ALS function to build a recommendation system. The function accepts as input an rdd comprising rows of the form: *(user_id, item_id, rating)*.

I would like to know what happens when the function sees two tuples with the same *user_id* and *item_id*. Is the function overwriting or averaging the values?

I went through the official documentation but did not find any clue.

Many thanks